# "Bei" mit gleicher Bedeutung wie "In"

Tags: meaning

In den folgenden Sätze können wir "in" anstatt "bei" benutzen? Wird die Bedeutung unterschiedlich?
Die Sätze sind von Goethe-Zertifikat B1 Wortlist.

- *Bei schönem Wetter könnten wir ein Picknick machen*
- *Meine Tochter hat bei einem Wettbewerb gewonnen*

Comment: 1) Nein. 2) Ja.

Comment: @infinitezero Danke, können Sie mehr erklären?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepositions are the bane of anyone trying to learn a second language. Trying to translate them directly can only lead to confusion. The best approach seems to be to discover each of the possible uses and meanings of each preposition, and figure what is the best match in the other language for that use and meaning. That should, in fact, be the approach you use for any word, but failure to do so with prepositions leads to failure more certainly and spectacularly than with other words.

I'll be refering to the [DWDS entry](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bei#1). The first example seems to be using meaning II.1.a, which I render as "taking place at the same time as another process or event". In this case the event is *schönem Wetter*. There are temporal meanings for *in*, but they're used with periods of time, not processes or events. So there is no meaning of *in* that would fit in the sentence.

The second example is more spacial in nature and I think definition I.1.b is the best match. I'd render it as "in the domain of, the home or offices of", which does overlap with some senses of *in*. So *Meine Tochter hat in einem Wettbewerb gewonnen,* does seem to be a possibility.

Word for word, the second example translates as "My daughter won at/in a competition," and there are several choices for how to say the "at/in" part in German, and there are presumably subtle differences in meaning according to which word is used. If it were my sentence I'd avoid the whole issue by eliminating the preposition entirely: *Meine Tochter hat einen Wettbewerb gewonnen.*

Apologies for not answering in German. English is my first language and it's still difficult for me to write in German. I honestly didn't notice that the question was in German; that kind of thing seems to happen to me more and more, which is good in a way since it means that I'm at least understanding German better and better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer